# What is the "question" when using Dynamic Memory Networks to do part-of-speech tagging and sentiment analysis?

Tags: deep-learning, natural-language-processing, papers, question-answering

In the paper [Ask Me Anything: Dynamic Memory Networks for Natural Language Processing](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.07285) the authors described a Dynamic Memory Network in the context of question answering. Then, they also tested the network on sentiment classification and part-of-speech tagging. In those applications, what is the 'question' being inputted to the network?